# Porto Theme Demo 19 Customization

Tags: magento, themes

I am trying to customize my site from Demo 19 if anyone has experience with porto demo 19 customization it would be awesome

http://www.newsmartwave.net/magento/porto/index.php/demo19_en

Im trying to change the jumbotron pictures from fashion to other pics and idk where to change it as well as the icons on the homepage. Demo 19 has the nice page menu on the side but i want to customize it to add icons. Will i have to customize the actual files to do these things or is there a way through magento to do it?

Comment: find static block name like slider 19 that can be help you for customization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the template files inside smartwave/porto/template

Mostly, you can do everything via Magento's CSS overides. :)